# Include route provider templateurl path in view div Angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-routing

I have below route provider setup like:

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/slapppoc/Style Library/TAC/Views/tarification/home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
         /*
    resolve: {
        // This function will be called before any controller/views are instantiated.
        'initializeApplication': function (initializationService) {                
            return initializationService.initializeApplicationData;
        }
    }*/
})
.when('/createTarif', {
    templateUrl: '/slapppoc/Style Library/TAC/Views/tarification/createTarif.html',
    controller: 'tarificationController'
 })
 .when('/search', {
    templateUrl: '/slapppoc/Style Library/TAC/Views/tarification/Search.html',
    controller: 'searchController'
 })     
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

Now i have div setup like this in my main view -

```
<div ng-init="tab=1" >
        <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 1">tab 1</div>
        <div class="cb" ng-click="tab = 2">tab 2</div>

        <div ng-show="tab == 1">
               How to include html templateurl path here  (createtarif.html)
        </div>

        <div ng-show="tab == 2">
                   How to include html templateurl path here  (search.html)
        </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**

I have also tried ng-include directive like this-

```
<div ng-include src="'/slapppoc/Style Library/TAC/Views/tarification/createTarif.html'"></div>
```

But it does not work also.

So I want to include the html from templateurl in subsequent div.How can I do that? So while switching divs html contents would auto change.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ng-include like this :  ( without `src` )

`<div ng-include="'/slapppoc/Style Library/TAC/Views/tarification/createTarif.html'" />`

instead of this

`<div ng-include src="'/slapppoc/Style Library/TAC/Views/tarification/createTarif.html'"></div>`

---

the example from official documentation

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <select ng-model="template" ng-options="t.name for t in templates">
        <option value="">(blank)</option>
    </select>
    url of the template: <code>{{template.url}}</code>
    <hr/>
    <div class="slide-animate-container">
        <div class="slide-animate" ng-include="template.url"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check ng-include documentation   https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude
there is example.

there is another way. you can add new element directive and include it

Comment: I cant understand what mean 'doesnt work'. your template is not appeared or doesnt work its functional?